# c++ overloaded functions with equal implementation

Tags: c++, overloading

I have two overloaded functions like

```
void f(int);
void f(std::string);
```

And two overloaded functions `g` with the same prototypes as `f`, but which are simple wrappers to `f`, hence their implementations are exactly the same:

```
void g(int n) { f(n);}
void g(std::string n) { f(n); }
```

Is there a way of avoiding writing twice the implementation of `g`? I know this can be done by declaring `g` via a template like

```
template<typename T> g(T n) { f(n);}
```

but then I'll have to type the type in the function call like in

```
g<int>(2);
g<std::string>("42");
```

I wander what's the correct way of avoiding writing twice the implementation of `g` without forcing the user to explicitly write the typename in each function call?

Comment: "but then I'll have to type the type in the function", no, you don't have to. Template argument deduction does that for  you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“but then I'll have to type the type in the function”, no, you don't have to. **Template argument deduction** does that for  you. So, a function template is a practical solution.

The one you've written,

> ```
> template<typename T> g(T n) { f(n);}
> ```

is fine except that it needs a `void` return type.

---

You can support **move-optimizations** as follows:

```
template< class Arg >
void g( Arg&& arg ) { f( std::forward<Arg>( arg ) ); }
```

Here the `&&` does not denote an rvalue reference but a so called **universal reference**, because it's applied to a template argument that can already be a reference.

The effect of that is that `std::forward` in most cases can reproduce exactly the kind of the actual argument, which is called **perfect forwarding**.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way of avoiding writing twice the implementation of g?

Yes, there is.

> I know this can be done by declaring g via a template like

There you go.

> but then I'll have to type the type in the function call

No, you don't. You can let the compiler to deduce the types:

```
g(2);
g("42");
```